# yii: internationalization (i18n) and dynamic url manager

Tags: routes, yii, url-routing

I would like to know a better way to implement "internationalization (i18n)" and "dynamic URL management" in Yii framework.

A (difficult to maintain) temporary solution:

```
// protected/config/main.php
'language' => 'es',
...
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>array(
            // pages
            'es/turismo/<slug:>' => array('visit/page', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'es'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),
            'it/visita/<slug:>' => array('visit/page', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'it'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),
            'en/travel/<slug:>' => array('visit/page', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'en'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),
            'turismo/<slug:>' => array('visit/page', 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),

            // home
            'es/turismo' => array('visit/index', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'es'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),
            'it/visita' => array('visit/index', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'it'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),
            'en/travel' => array('visit/index', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'en'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),

            // contact us
            'es/contactenos' => array('site/contact', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'es'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),
            'it/contattaci' => array('site/contact', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'it'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),
            'en/contact-us' => array('site/contact', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'en'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),

        ),
    ),
...


// protected/controllers/VisitController.php
...
public function actionIndex($lang = 'es'){
    Yii::app()->language = $lang;
    ...
}
public function actionPage($slug, $lang = 'es'){
    Yii::app()->language = $lang;
    ...
}
...
```

This implies, new config 'urlManager' rules for each controller and always pass the $lang parameter for each controller action. A live example:

[montmartrebutte.com](http://www.montmartrebutte.com/)

I tried some other options without success:

[Yii Framework Forum: Dynamic URL manager routes](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/5178-dynamic-url-manager-routes/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rule:

```
'<lang:(es|it|en)>/(turismo|visita|travel)/<slug:>' => array('visit/page', 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),
```

Controller:

```
class VisitController extends Controller
{
    public function actionPage($slug)
    {

    }
}
```

Parent controller (if you don't use modules):

```
class Controller extends CController
{
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        Yii::app()->language = Yii::app()->request->getQuery('lang', 'es');
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
}
```

Comment: umm... i've tried and seems not to work. produces the following url structure: `<baseUrl>/visit/page/slug/montmartre-paris-best-places-to-visit-sacre-coeur/lang/en` instead of `<baseUrl>/en/travel/montmartre-paris-best-places-to-visit-sacre-coeur.html`

Comment: I've just been used your link **/en/travel/montmartre-paris-best-places-to-visit-sacre-coeur.html** and got this result **in the controller**: _lang: en; slug: montmartre-paris-best-places-to-visit-sacre-coeur;_ If you used my solution correctly, please give detailed result of your experiment: where exactly was an error.

Comment: Er, I don't ask you to show the results on production site. Just tell what errors did you get when you tried my solution, please. It must work correctly.

Comment: now i try removing the 'defaultParams' part of the rule: `'<lang:(es|it|en)>/(turismo|visita|travel)/<slug:>' => array('visit/page', 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),` and i get the following: `<baseUrl>/es/(turismo%7Cvisita%7Ctravel)/informacion-de-interes.html`

Comment: but, the _"always pass the $lang parameter for each controller action"_ problem is solved without this change: `'<lang:(es|it|en)>/(turismo|visita|travel)/<slug:>' => array('visit/page', 'defaultParams' => array('lang' => 'es'), 'urlSuffix' => '.html'),` ... and, it's already a really big help :)

Comment: Oh, yes, 'defaultParams' is a superfluous in my solution, I've corrected it. If you've used it and everything is OK, please don't forget to accept the answer, it's important for the community.