# YII urlManager rewrite singe URL with multiple parameters

Tags: php, yii

Ok, removed my previous question and reformulated the new one, otherwise no one would understand, sorry. So here the problem that's left:

So I want to rewrite an URL to a single word which works with zero, one and two parameters, but not with 3:

Original url with 2 paramaters:

```
index.php?r=site/page&view=exposities&tijd=nu
```

urlmanager rule:

```
'exposities_nu'=>array('site/page', 'defaultParams' => array('view' => 'exposities', 'tijd'=>'nu')),
```

result:

```
/exposities_nu/
```

**Now what doesn't work:**

Original url with 3 parameters:

```
index.php?r=site/page&view=exposities&tijd=vestiging&locatie=1
```

urlmanager rule:

```
'knsm'=>array('site/page', 'defaultParams' => array('view' => 'exposities', 'tijd'=>'nu', 'locatie'=>'1')),
```

result:

```
index.php?r=site/page&view=exposities&tijd=vestiging&locatie=1
```

---

Does anyone why this last url isn't shortened to /knsm/?

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12082021/yii-advanced-url-rewrite>
may be this will solve ur problem...

Comment: I think this doesn't change the way I have to make up the rules... Interesting solution anyway, but I doesn't help me at the moment I think..

Comment: navigating to www.website.com/knsm/ doesn't work? With your exact code, I am able to navigate to www.website.com/knsm/ and can `echo` the default params using `$_GET['view']`, `$_GET['tijd']` and `$_GET['locatie']` - in other words, your code is fine.

Comment: ah, you're right. Navigation to the url works, but he writes it wrong when there're more then 2 characters. So don't know why he writes the complete string again when I add a third character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you didn't set the url in the URL Manager right. See this example:

```
return array(
    ......
    'components'=>array(
        ......
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                'post/<id:\d+>/<title:.*?>'=>'post/view',
                'posts/<tag:.*?>'=>'post/index',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Also you have to create you URLs correct:

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('post/view', array(
            'id'=>$this->id,
            'title'=>$this->title,
        ));
```